# Integration Services Catalog - Access To Path Is Denied

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Cannot seem to find any concise information on this at all so trying my luck here.

Recently have setup Integration Services Catalogs because at present all our SSIS packages are stored within a folder and just ran as a File. We wish to move these, which has worked fine.

I have created a basic SSIS Package that puts a Username into a SQL Table and then also a File System Task to Delete a File.

When the package is ran from the Catalog via SSMS it completes the SQL side of things perfectly fine, placing both the Username running the package and the data into the SQL table, however it fails on the File System Task with

```
"File System Task: Error: An error occured with the following error message : "Access to the path "xxxx" is denied.
```

I have changed the SQL Agent Job on the SQL Server to have the permissions of our Administrator Account with no luck.

I can confirm the folder in question is Shared, it has FULL Read/Write Permission to "Everyone" and yet I still get this error.

I even went to the trouble of creating a new folder and just enabled full sharing to everybody on it - I still get the same access is denied.

Seen a previous post on stackoverflow about NETWORK SERVICE being added, can also confirm that this has full permission to the folder and thus it rules this out also.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: From your description *"When the package is ran from the Catalog via SSMS it completes the SQL side of things perfectly fine, placing both the Username running the package and the data into the SQL table, however it fails on the File System Task with"* is sounds like you aren't using the agent to run the task. The agent runs an SSISDB task when you (unsurprisingly) use the Agent. When you run a package in SISSDB via T-SQL you use the credentials of whoever ran the T-sQL. Sounds like what you have here is the classic double hop issue. SSMS->SQL Server->File System

Comment: @Larnu I have full Owner Access to the SQL Server in question, I'm also an Administrator on our system so if anything I have more access than anyone else.

Comment: Then it's definitely the double hop issue. Access level is meaningless is you're authenticating as anonymous.